# Waiting for two events in no specific order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

I am writing a node/angular web app that deals with dynamically generated forms, with the form data being communicated over sockets. I have come into an issue where if I switch Controllers, sometimes the socket event (containing the questions to ask) is emitted before the new controller is ready to process it.  I thought I had solved this by having a top level 'SocketController', which handles all socket communication and passes it down to child controllers by emitting events, but it turns out I only reduced the frequency at which this issue appears.

I could wait for the controller/view content to be ready before passing the questions down, but since these two events occur in no particular order and, one of them contains the data, it becomes alot of messy looking code.

I can't help but feel I am overlooking a simpler solution.
Is there any common pattern/technique for dealing with this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a simple factory service to handle the questions.
`.factory('QuestionService', function(){
        return {questions: null}
})`
The socket controller stores the questions in this service when received. 
`socket.on(eventName, function(questions){
        QuestionService.questions = questions;
})`
Each state's controller watches this value, updating the form onload (if questions are present) and whenever a new set of questions is received.
`$scope.$watch(function(){ return QuestionService.questions }, function(questions){
        if(questions)
            $scope.$broadcast('form:question', questions);
 });`

Whenever state changes, the questions are set back to null.
`$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){
       QuestionService.questions = null;
});`

Answer (score 0):

This is where promise composition is really handy.

The things you're waiting on probably already have promises you can use (if not, you can promise-ify them). So get a promise from each of them (say, `p1` and `p2`), then use `$q.all` to get a callback when both promises have been settled:

```
$q.all([p1, p2])
    .then(function(results) {
       // Use results[0] (the result of p1) and results[1] (the result of p2)
    }).catch(function() {
       // Handle error
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using $q.allSettled design in the link below to chain the promises until they complete.

```
$q.allSettled([promise0, promise1])
     .then(function (data) {
       // handle sockets here
      });
```

More specifics and design considerations are [here](http://www.codeducky.org/q-allsettled/)

To make the promise do the following:

```
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  socket.on("", function(service){
      // success
     resolve(); or service.success()
      // error
     reject(); or service.error()
}
});
```

Comment: The only issue I have with this is that one event may repeat multiple times before the other does(i.e. multiple sets of questions within one state/view).  Will this result in my socket handler waiting for a 'ready' event on each question?